# Password protection static app running on nginx

Tags: nginx, static, passwords, password-protection, webfaction

Is there a way to protect 1 folder on the website running on static nginx?

Example:

http://www.example.com/protected-folder/

If I load domain it should be public, if I load "protected-folder" it should ask for a

password. Is there a way to achieve this?

To help you I am running it on "Webfaction" host as a Static App.

Thank you.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/auth_basic

Comment: Since you seem to be on webfaction: http://docs.webfaction.com/software/static.html?highlight=static%20password#password-protecting-a-directory-with-a-static-cgi-php-app